# Sort a string array with Collections based on the content of the split string

Tags: java, collections

I have a String array where there is a white space in the middle. I want to sort the contents based on the first substring before the white space, and then the substring after the white space.

For example, if my array looks like this: `{"Henry 123", "Henry 234", "David 123", "David 234"}`, in the end I want `{"David 123", "David 234", "Henry 123", "Henry 234"}`.

I tried implement a new comparator below:

```
import java.util.*;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String[] str_arr = {"Henry 123", "Henry 234", "David 123", "David 234"};

        Collections.sort(str_arr, new Comparator<String>(){
            
            public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
                String[] str1 = s1.split(" ");
                String[] str2 = s2.split(" ");
                if(str1[0].compareTo(str2[0]) != 0) {
                    return str1[0].compareTo(str2[0]);
                }
                return str1[1].compareTo(str2[1]); 
            }            
        });
        
        for (int i = 0; i < str_arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%s, ", str_arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

But I am getting this error:

> MyClass.java:7: error: no suitable method found for sort(String[],<anonymous Comparator>)
> Collections.sort(str_arr, new Comparator(){
> ^
> method Collections.<T#1>sort(List<T#1>) is not applicable
> (cannot infer type-variable(s) T#1
> (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
> method Collections.<T#2>sort(List<T#2>,Comparator<? super T#2>) is not applicable
> (cannot infer type-variable(s) T#2
> (argument mismatch; String[] cannot be converted to List<T#2>))
> where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
> T#1 extends Comparable<? super T#1> declared in method <T#1>sort(List<T#1>)
> T#2 extends Object declared in method <T#2>sort(List<T#2>,Comparator<? super T#2>)
> 1 error

This error sounds like Collections framework does not support sorting strings, which does not make much sense.

Comment: What order would you want `{ "Henry 123", "Henry 23", "David 53", "David 234" }` to be sorted?  Please show expected result.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but splitting the string seems unnecessary. You are comparing first string and if they are the same you compare the second, but just comparing the entire string will give exactly the same result...

Comment: @magicmn True, I was initially thinking comparing strings of digits and digits will yield the same result, but as WJS pointed out, it was not the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way.

```
String[] arr = { "Henry 123", "Henry 234", "David 123",
        "David 234" };

Comparator<String> comp =
        Comparator.comparing(s -> s.split("\\s+"),
                Comparator.comparing((String[] a) -> a[0])
                        .thenComparing(a -> a[1]));

Arrays.sort(arr,comp);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr))
```

prints

```
[David 123, David 234, Henry 123, Henry 234]
```

If you want to compare the second value as an `int` then change to.

```
...thenComparingInt(a -> Integer.parseInt(a[1])));
```

Remember that comparing numbers as strings is lexical not numerical so the results can vary. For example, comparing `[55, 123]` as strings would result in  `[123, 55]` since `55` is lexically greater than `123`. And the reason your solution didn't work is that arrays are not collections which is what `Collections.sort()` expects.

Answer (score 3):

You have a `String` *array*, which the `Collection.sort` method indeed does not support sorting. `Collections.sort` is for sorting `List`s.

You should use `Arrays.sort` instead:

```
Arrays.sort(str_arr, (s1, s2) -> {
    String[] str1 = s1.split(" ");
    String[] str2 = s2.split(" ");
    int firstPartcomparison = str1[0].compareTo(str2[0]);
    if(firstPartcomparison != 0) {
        return firstPartcomparison;
    }
    return str1[1].compareTo(str2[1]);
});
```

Comment: This is also super helpful, but the other answer gave a more in-depth explanation and alerted a pitfall. Unfortunately I can only accept one answer :(

Comment: @kd8 Oh right. I didn't notice that! I probably would have noticed if some of the numbers have different numbers of digits :)