# How Arrays.sort() works on numeric Strings

Tags: java, arrays, string

Greetings to the community!

I browsed a lot over the internet but couldn't find the answer in my case. My question is that when we provide an array of numeric strings to the Arrays.sort() how it sorts them. Like I have a string array that contains numbers

`String[] numerics= {"1","2","3","12","-7"}`

and when I apply

```
  Arrays.sort(numerics)
```

Output comes as

**Before Sorting**

[1, 2, 3, 12, -7]

**After Applying Arrays.sort()**

[-7, 1, 12, 2, 3]

I want to know how Arrays.sort() sorts this string array.?

Comment: "*I want to know how Arrays.sort() sorts this string array.?*" - By lexicographic order. See [the documentation of `String::compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String))

Comment: Did you know you can see the code of that method and just debug through it?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I have studied a bit about lexicographic ordering but could not relate it to my case (my string) or was unable to figure out how it worked in this case.

Comment: takendarkk I know. In my case Arrays.sort(Object[] os) was  called

Comment: This recently game up in another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70816096/1552534)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting numbers represented as string won't work, as you have already found out.

If you look at the ASCII table you can see that the hyphen comes before all numeric digits in the table.

https://www.asciitable.com/

That is why your negative number (the hyphen, actually) comes first.

As for how the sort works, it would be a character-by-character comparison.
In other words, the sort would compare the first character of each string, then the second character of each string, and so on...

If you must compare the strings as numbers, you could convert each string to a number, sort that array, then convert them back to strings.

**If you're really dealing with numbers, it would be far better to store and work with them as numbers (integers or decimals).**

Comment: The point was not to sort the numbers through the sort() method but just to ask how the system works if we provide them such strings. But your ASCII point cleared this question to some extent. I was also thinking that they might be comparing through their asci code. If a better answer comes from a senior, it would be appreciable. Otherwise I will accept your answer. Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @Lee Boozer is correct. Strings are compared char by char until the first difference is found. The first different chars found are compared as ASCII and the result is the result of your String comparison. SO obviously with this "3" will be greater than "27". So, you can convert your Strings to Integers (or Long) and compare them or you can use an Open source library called MgntUtils that has a `VersionComparator` class that takes Strings such as "3.5.2" and "15.7" and compares them by comparing number by number delimited by "." so any numeric string like "5" or "27" will also be a valid version and as such could be compared with each other by `VersionComparator`. One drawback it doesn't work with negative numbers, and it is so by design. Here is [Javadoc](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/textutils/VersionComparator.html). The library could be found on Maven central [here](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) and on Github including Javadoc and source code [here](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases)